# ¿Cómo asignar un valor dependiendo la opción que tome?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una aplicación la cual me filtra por id la información correspondiente en una tabla y manejo dos campos de id diferentes. Quiero que, dependiendo del campo que escoja, me muestre ese id en el mismo campo.
A continuación dejo el código.

```
 <h4 className="py-3">TABLA SELECCION DE PERSONAL</h4>
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table
            id="dataTable"
            className="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered"
          >
            <thead className="table-dark">
              <tr className="text-center">
                <th></th>
                <th>REGIONAL</th>
                <th>RECLUTADOR</th>
                <th>FECHA DE RECLUTAMIENTO</th>
                <th>FECHA DE ENTREVISTA</th>
                <th>HORA DE ENTREVISTA</th>
                <th>CAMPAÑA</th>
                <th>CARGO</th>
                <th>NOMBRE DEL CANDIDATO</th>
                <th>DOCUMENTO DEL CANDIDATO</th>
                <th>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</th>
                <th>DIRECCION DEL CANDIDATO</th>
                <th>BARRIO/LOCALIDAD</th>
                <th>CONTACTO DEL CANDIDATO</th>
                <th>FUENTE DE RECLUTAMIENTO</th>
                <th>OBSERVACION DE LA LLAMADA</th>
                <th>ASISTENCIA A LA ENTREVISTA</th>
                <th>PRESELECCIONADO POR SELECCION</th>
                <th>PRESELECCIONADO POR BPE</th>
                <th>PRESELECCIONADO POR JEFE INMEDIATO</th>
                <th>OBSERVACIONES</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {record.map((name) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-warning form-control"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal"
                        data-bs-target="#myModal"
                        onClick={() => editData(name)}
                      >
                        <i className="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true" />
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>{name.gen_ciu_apli}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_rec}</td>
                  <td>{mostrarFecha(name.gen_fh_rec)}</td>
                  <td>{mostrarFecha(name.gen_ent)}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_hr}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_camp}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_car_apli}</td>
                  <td>
                    {name.gen_pri_ape +
                      " " +
                      name.gen_seg_ape +
                      " " +
                      name.gen_pri_nom +
                      " " +
                      name.gen_seg_nom}
                  </td>
                  <td>{filtro === "CEDULA" ? name.ide : name.pep}</td> // ESTE ES EL CAMPO
                  <td>{mostrarFecha(name.gen_fh_nac)}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_dir}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_bar}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_cel}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_fue_rec}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_obs_lla}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_asi_ent}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_pre_sel}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_pre_pus}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_pre_jef_inm}</td>
                  <td>{name.gen_obs}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

y se me ocurrió hacer una condición en el campo donde quiero que se muestre pero no funciona; las variables afectadas son `gen_ide` y `gen_pep` donde digo que, si es igual a la cédula, me muestre el dato correspondiente, y solo necesito eso ya que las variables ya tienen información almacenada y solo quiero que se muestre dependiendo la opción por la cual la filtré.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De dónde viene le estado `filtro`? Comparte esa pieza de código, saludos

Answer (score 0):

resulta que logre resolver el problema, lo que hice fue tomar el valor de la variable la cual me filtraba y funciono, así quedo la solución

```
gen_nac === 'COLOMBIA' ? gen_ide : gen_pep
```

Esta fue la solución que encontre.
Saludos